# Integer Python Program

Tags: python

I want to write a program which does:
If the input number is positive, just print it out;
If the input number is negative, print the abs number;
if not a number, print "Error"

I don't know how to do the last step.

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you tried the "try:" method that shows up on Google?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you said:

```
num = input( 'need a number:' )
try :
    num = int(num)
    print( abs(num) )
except ValueError :
    print( 'not a number' )
```

Comment: You need to move `print( abs(num) )` into the `try` block, otherwise you'll get a second error trying to call `abs` on a string.